# Merge Word Documents (Office Interop & .NET), Keeping Formatting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, office-interop, office-2007

I'm having some difficulty merging multiple word documents together using Microsoft Office Interop Assemblies (Office 2007) and ASP.NET 3.5. I'm able to merge the documents, but some of my formatting is missing (namely the fonts and images).

My current merge code is shown below.

```
private void CombineDocuments() {
        object wdPageBreak = 7;
        object wdStory = 6;
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object oFalse = false;
        object oTrue = true;
        string fileDirectory = @"C:\documents\";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        string[] wordFiles = Directory.GetFiles(fileDirectory, "*.doc");
        for (int i = 0; i < wordFiles.Length; i++) {
            string file = wordFiles[i];
            wDoc.Application.Selection.Range.InsertFile(file, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oFalse);
            wDoc.Application.Selection.Range.InsertBreak(ref wdPageBreak);
            wDoc.Application.Selection.EndKey(ref wdStory, ref oMissing);
        }
        string combineDocName = Path.Combine(fileDirectory, "Merged Document.doc");
        if (File.Exists(combineDocName))
            File.Delete(combineDocName);
        object combineDocNameObj = combineDocName;
        wDoc.SaveAs(ref combineDocNameObj, ref m_WordDocumentType, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
    }
```

I don't care necessarily how this is accomplished. It could output via PDF if it had to. I just want the formatting to carry over.

Comment: Don't ever use Office Interop from an ASP.NET application. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: Downvoted and voted to close because, as-is, someone is going to decide that this question means it's ok to use Office Interop from ASP.NET.

Answer (score -1):

While adding the documents you are skipping the Template name, that why ut's missing the format.

It should look like

```
string defaultTemplate="your template name with full path";
```

**OR**

Default template name

```
string defaultTemplate="Normal.dot";

wordApplication.Documents.Add(ref defaultTemplate,............
```

Use this link as Ref: http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2007/05/23/how-to-merge-multiple-microsoft-word-documents-in-c.aspx