# When merging word documents I get a blank page after each document

Tags: c#, ms-word

Application is a combination of WPF and C#, all code that I am having issues with below are in the C# portion...

I have an application that generates some HTML and saves it to a PDF using MS Word Interop.  I want to give the user the option to include a header or footer they have created seperatly from my application should they choose to do so.  I have managed to accomplish this but my problem that I am facing is this.  If any of the documents end at the bottom of the page when the next document is inserted there is a blank page in between.

Rough example:

- Cover Page (Doesn't hit the end of the page)
- Stuff genereated from my application (Hits the bottom of the page)
- Blank Page
- Footer (Hits the bottom of the page)
- Blank Page

So if someone could look at how I am doing this and let me know what is wrong in my logic, or give me a hint at where to look that would be awesome.  Thanks everyone and let me know if I need to provide anymore clarification.

This code was inspired by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512656/merge-word-documents-office-interop-net-keeping-formatting)

```
//Itterate through all wordFiles that have been passed in, in a string array
for ( int i = 0; i < wordFiles.Length; i++)
{
   //Get the current word file
   string file = wordFiles[i];
   //Insert the file
   wDoc.Application.Selection.Range.InsertFile(file,
                                               ref oMissing, 
                                               ref oMissing, 
                                               ref oMissing, 
                                               ref oFalse);
   if(i != 0)
      //if not add a page break
      wDoc.Application.Selection.Range.InsertBreak(ref wdPageBreak);

   // Moves to the end of the current page 
   // (Same funcionality of pressing the "End" Key)
   wDoc.Application.Selection.EndKey(ref wdStory, ref oMissing);
}
```

Comment: the add page break is the culprit, bottom of a page + page break means new blank page is what i would hazard a guess at

Comment: just as a test, pass it a cover page that hits the bottom of the page. as it IS the 0th it should skip the page break bit. See if that still create a blank page after it or not

Comment: @RhysW I initially found this issue because the cover page hit the bottom of the page.  The above code works just fine so long as the previous page does not hit the bottom of the page.  So in this instance the cover page will not have a blank page after it.  However if the Cover page did indeed hit the bottom of the page there will be a blank page after it...does that make sense or am I not explaining it that well? Sorry it's kind of a hard issue to discribe...

Comment: ah ok, so its not the page break doing it, as the 0th is made to avoid the page break. atleast we ruled out one posibility XD