# How would I merge multiple documents together in pywin32?

Tags: python, ms-word, pywin32

I am working on a script that needs to grab all of the documents out of a directory and merge them together with comments and formatting.

I know VBS can do this but VBS is very limited and slow when it comes to parsing documents. Especially in word 2013.

I've looked over the documentation of pywin32 but couldn't find anything.

I would think it would be something as simple as

```
word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.AddDocument()
doc.InsertDocument(Filename)
```

There isn't much code to show because all the code I have currently is used after the documents are merged.

Answer (score 2):

The code will look like this:

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = False

output = word.Documents.Add()

output.Application.Selection.Range.InsertFile('second.doc')
output.Application.Selection.Range.InsertBreak()
output.Application.Selection.Range.InsertFile('first.doc')

output.SaveAs('output.doc')
output.Close()
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512656/merge-word-documents-office-interop-net-keeping-formatting) question also may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for this!
Didn't work quite out of the box: I needed to feed absolute paths to the functions.

`output.Application.Selection.Range.InsertFile(str(Path('first.docx').absolute()))`
`output.SaveAs(str(Path.cwd() / 'output.docx'))`